# If two equations when squared result in the same third equation, in what circumstances do the original two equations have the same solutions?

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus

I was solving the following problem from Spivak's Calculus (Chapter 10, problem 14):

> Prove that the tangent lines to an ellipse or hyperbola intersect
> these sets only once.

I solved the problem for ellipses, and in the middle of the solution there was the following step:

$$b\sqrt{1-\frac{x^2}{a^2}}=(x-x_0) \frac{-b x_0}{a^2\sqrt{1-\frac{x_0^2}{a^2}}}+ b\sqrt{1-\frac{x_0^2}{a^2}}\tag{1}$$

Then I went to solve for hyperbolas, and reached the following equation:

$$b\sqrt{\frac{x^2}{a^2}-1}=(x-x_0) \frac{b x_0}{a^2\sqrt{\frac{x_0^2}{a^2}-1}}+ b\sqrt{\frac{x_0^2}{a^2}-1}\tag{2}$$

Squaring $(1)$ and $(2)$ results in the same equation. The solution manual says that "squaring $(1)$ and $(2)$ produces the same result, so the solutions of $(2)$ are also $x=c$" (I am using $x_0$ instead of $c$ in my equation), ie the solutions to the non-squared equations are the same. **But how do we know this is true?**

Let's consider a simpler example:

$$x=2\tag{3}$$
$$x=-2\tag{4}$$

When we square $(3)$ and $(4)$ we get

$$x^2=4\tag{5}$$

The solutions to $(5)$ are $2$ and $-2$, but the non-squared equations do not have the same solution.

Comment: I can't help but wonder if we're missing some necessary context here. What variable(s) are we solving for? What exactly did the solution manual say after "also", and what did it say about $(1)$ for comparison? Equation $(1)$ requires that $x \leq a$ and $x_0 < a$ but $(2)$ requires that $x\geq a$ and $x_0 > a,$ so we are clearly not going to find the exact same values in both equations.

Comment: We are solving for $x$. In $(1)$, the left-hand side represents the top part of an ellipse, the right-hand side represents an equation of the tangent line to the ellipse at $(x_0, f(x_0)$. When we solve for $x$, we reach the single solution $x=x_0$, showing that the tangent line touches the top part of the ellipse only once. I've amended the question with the solution manual text after the "also...". It simply says that the solution to $(2)$ is also $x=x_0$ (though I kept it verbatim in the question: the manual uses $c$ rather than $x_0$.

Comment: I agree, the equations (1) and (2) have non-intersecting implicit domains (in reals), so can't possibly have the same (non-empty) solution sets. The text just means that $x=x_0$ is the unique solution by the same reasoning in both cases.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solutions are not the same.

Indeed you can see that your conditions are different from both equations.

$x_0$ is a pivot with regard to $a$ in the domains of the equation validity.

What your manual is saying is not true in a strict sense, but it is "acceptable" in a common langage kind of way.

Indeed you will find $x=x_0$ as the solution in both cases, but this $x_0$ is not the same (with regard to $a$) in both equations!

However, there might be a deeper reason to that, that could be demonstrated. Indeed the excentricity of the equation indeed depends on whether or not $x_0>a$ or the contrary, and this leads to the equation you found.
Is it possible to treat both cases at the same time with the same equation by using absolute values? You might want to give it a go.